# how to make input field based on json response

Tags: json, ajax, response

I got 2 json response. 1st as

```
{"Request":[{"Key":"Consumer No","Value":"Enter Value"},{"Key":"BU","Value":"Enter Value"}]}
```

and
2nd as

```
{"Request":[{"Key":"Customer ID / Account ID","Value":"Enter Value"}]}
```

i want to create input field based on the response i got

using ajax i get above response so i want to create input field based on json response

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: yes i am using jQuery

Comment: What did you tried for solving it ? Can you add your attempts in question ?